# How I can cut a JTable into several parts of which each part have its own title?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

How I can cut a `JTable` into several parts of which each part has its own title,  noting that all the data exists in the same database?

I want to do something like this.

[image]

Comment: Multiple JTables, perhaps?

Comment: it is the same jtable i think because there is just one Title line

Comment: @imenltf, `it is the same jtable` - no it is not a JTable. A Swing JTable does not support that type of functionality.

Comment: @camickr  so haw can i do it ? can you help me please ??

Comment: I'd use one table with an extra column to delineate between Accessory / Printer. Then implement a row sorter / filter that allows the user to group or filter the data as they wish. Either that or use entirely separate tables as suggested by @JoeC. You'll probably find the user prefers a functional (yet 'not exciting') GUI to whatever kewl effect it is you are trying to achieve.

Comment: You could layout a `JTableHeader` and several `JTable`s in a container, but you'll have to take over the column re-sizing and movement, which would be a mess of additional code

Comment: @MadProgrammer, `but you'll have to take over the column re-sizing and movement, which would be a mess of additional code` - sharing the TableColumnModel seems to work (in simple testing anyways).

Comment: Agree with @AndrewThompson suggestion to add an additional column. You might be able to get two separate table working, but you would then lose sortering/filtering functionality on the table as a whole.

Comment: @camickr That's probably a reasonable approach

Comment: but i can't know exactly the number of parties because every time I add a product family to my database I must automatically add another parity to my [jTable] 
this picture  is just an example

Comment: @camickr Out of curiosity, does it animate the column movement across both tables?

Comment: @MadProgrammer, no, the column jumps when it gets half way.

Comment: @MadProgrammer, just edited the code to also set the table header of the second table to the table header of the first and now the columns of both tables are animated. So much for quick tests as I actually had this when I first tested but didn't think it was needed so I removed it :)

Comment: @camickr Ah, awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple example to give you some ideas:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TableSharedHeader extends JPanel
{
    JComboBox comboBox;

    TableSharedHeader()
    {

        JTable table1 = new JTable(5, 3);
        JTable table2 = new JTable(5, 3);
        table2.setTableHeader( table1.getTableHeader() );
        table2.setColumnModel( table1.getColumnModel() );

        JPanel tablePanel = new JPanel();
        tablePanel.setLayout( new BoxLayout(tablePanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS) );

        tablePanel.add( new JLabel("First table") );
        tablePanel.add(table1);
        tablePanel.add( new JLabel("Second table") );
        tablePanel.add(table2);

        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( tablePanel );
        scrollPane.setColumnHeaderView( table1.getTableHeader() );
        add( scrollPane );
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TableSharedHeader");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new TableSharedHeader());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> createAndShowGUI() );
/*
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
*/
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much to all of you for your help :D :D 
and thank you very very much camickr :D

Comment: @imenletaief, note the update to the code to share the table header so that both columns animation when you drag the table header.